# Has anyone installed Scrapy under Canopy distro

Tags: scrapy, enthought, canopy

I am new to Canopy. I have some data mining projects that I would like to do using Python. I was wondering if anyone was able to install Scrapy under Canopy? Is it easy to install packages outside of the main repository?

Comment: has anybody succeeded installing Scrapy with any other Python distribution?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is to try `pip install scrapy` from the command line (use the Canopy Command Prompt (Windows) or Canopy Terminal (OSX/Linux) found in the Tools menu; this ensures Canopy's User Python is on the PATH).

See this [article in the Enthought Knowledge Base about installing external packages into Canopy](https://support.enthought.com/entries/23389761-Installing-external-packages-into-Canopy-Python). It provides information on the steps required, including the use of `pip`, as well as other considerations you will want to be aware of when installing external packages.

Answer (score -1):

1)sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 627220E7
2)echo 'deb http://archive.scrapy.org/ubuntu scrapy main' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/scrapy.list
3)sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install scrapy-0.24
these are the above three steps which will install scrappy

even i had the same problem , below link helps you on this 
http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/ubuntu.html#topics-ubuntu

Comment: Link-only answers are strongly discouraged here at Stack Overflow.  Instead, [it is preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.